# How to create a dll from open source code in VC++

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015

I have downloaded the source code of the MPC-HC media player and compiled it in Visual Studio 2015. The project consists of numerous files and there isn't any useful documentation about the functions in the code. I need to create a dll from this code in Visual Studio for use in my Unity App. From the materials available online, I understand that I have to:

1. Create a new DLL project, using VS wizard.
2. Add existing source files to it.
3. Put into *.def file (which should have been created by the wizard)
   the names of the functions that I want to export from  the DLL.

I know how to create a new DLL project, but I have no clue regarding the rest of the two steps.

1. How do I add existing source files? Do I have to add all the files
   in the source? The source consists of a huge collection of .cpp, .h,
   .py, windows batch files, vc++ project files etc. Which among these
   do I need to add?
2. Are the functions that must be added to the *.def file different
   from the source files of step2? Do I need to understand the
   functions of the source code to identify which I need for playing my
   files in the video player or is there an easier method of doing so?

Please help!

Comment: ***How do I add existing source files?*** Right click on the project in solution explorer select Add then Existing Item. Or press `Shift-Alt-A`

Comment: You probably want to create a wrapper and not expose any of MPC-HC directly.

Comment: @drescherjm can you expand on that? What is a wrapper and how is it created and used in a dll?